# How to add DATE_ADD in query on laravel

Tags: laravel, date, eloquent, addition

I have such a query

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(do, INTERVAL 1 DAY)  AS od from termin
```

and I want to convert them to query in Eloquent

```
$tab = DB::table('termin')->get
```

how to do it
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your query as like below.

```
$tab = DB::table('termin')->selectRaw('DATE_ADD(do, INTERVAL 1 DAY)  AS od')->get();
```